# The anti-DRY pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I've written this set of code and feel that it's pretty poor
in quality. As you can see, in each of the four case statements
I'm ending up repeating an awful lot of the same code except for
a few variations in each case. Items that vary; session names, gridnames
and the ManagerContext group name. Can anyone take this mess of code and
show me a better way of doing this?

```
private void LoadGroup(string option)
{
    switch (option.ToUpper())
    {
        case "ALPHA":
            VList<T> alphaList = FetchInformation(
                                   ManagerContext.Current.Group1);

            if (Session["alphaGroup"] != null)
            {
                List<T> tempList = (List<T>)Session["alphaGroup"];
                alphaList.AddRange(tempList);
            }
            uxAlphaGrid.DataSource = alphaList;
            uxAlphaGrid.DataBind();
            break;
        case "BRAVO":
            VList<T> bravoList = FetchInformation(
                                   ManagerContext.Current.Group2);

            if (Session["bravoGroup"] != null)
            {
                List<T> tempList = (List<T>)Session["bravoGroup"];
                bravoList.AddRange(tempList);
            }
            uxBravoGrid.DataSource = bravoList;
            uxBravoGrid.DataBind();
            break;
        case "CHARLIE":
            VList<T> charlieList = FetchInformation(
                                   ManagerContext.Current.Group3);

            if (Session["charlieGroup"] != null)
            {
                List<T> tempList = (List<T>)Session["charlieGroup"];
                charlieList.AddRange(tempList);
            }
            uxCharlieGrid.DataSource = charlieList;
            uxCharlieGrid.DataBind();
            break;
        case "DELTA":
            VList<T> deltaList = FetchInformation(
                                   ManagerContext.Current.Group4);

            if (Session["deltaGroup"] != null)
            {
                List<T> tempList = (List<T>)Session["deltaGroup"];
                deltaList.AddRange(tempList);
            }
            uxDeltaGrid.DataSource = deltaList;
            uxDeltaGrid.DataBind();
            break;
        default:                
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is ManagerContext.Current.GroupX?  (enum, value, etc.?)

Comment: It's a property from the ManagerContext which returns a List<T> from session. The groupX matches up with the Session["Xteam"]. If it's not null add it to the list, otherwise skip it.

Comment: It seems strange to have Session["deltaTeam"], and later Session["deltaGroup"].. Is it a bug?..

Comment: I think I missed a name when I was cleaning it up. I'll fix that.

Comment: instead of hard-coding those strings, you should at the very least assign them to variables, and use the variables in their place. that prevents those kinds of mistakes ;)

Comment: @Dan - Yes, after I've gone through and made a single helper function I've gone back and started making the strings into variables. Just a much needed cleanup of the code. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should be able to extract the parts of the case to a parameterized helper function:

```
function helper(grp, grpname, dg) {
    VList<T> theList = FetchInformation(grp); 
    if (Session[grpname] != null) 
    { 
        List<T> tempList = (List<T>)Session[grpname]; 
        theList.AddRange(tempList); 
    } 
    dg.DataSource = theList; 
    dg.DataBind(); 
}

private void LoadGroup(string option) 
{ 
        switch (option.ToUpper()) 
        { 
                case "ALPHA": 
                        helper(ManagerContext.Current.Group1, "alphaGroup", uxAlphaGrid);
                        break; 
                case "BRAVO": 
                        helper(ManagerContext.Current.Group2, "bravoGroup", uxBravoGrid);
                        break; 
                case "CHARLIE": 
                        helper(ManagerContext.Current.Group3, "charlieGroup", uxCharlieGrid);
                        break; 
                case "DELTA": 
                        helper(ManagerContext.Current.Group4, "deltaGroup", uxDeltaGrid);
                        break; 
                default:                                 
                        break; 
        } 
}
```

That's one option and there is further refactoring, I'm sure.

For deeper refactorings, I would look at table-driving using a collection of option objects, potentially delegates, or similar.  The way this works is that the option would become an object instead of a string and the option would have properties which configure it and methods which invoke the proper delegates.  it really depends on the abstraction level you want to maintain.  Sometimes it pays to inherit from the regular controls and provide configuration information in the subclass so that they know how to load themselves.

There is not enough space here to really go into that depth of refactoring.

Comment: I was going to type up an object oriented way of doing this. This is simpler, but if you've got a lot more case statements you might consider creating a separate object that holds each of those properties. Then subclass for each separate option.

Comment: @Will, yes definitely, I think this is just a first step to stop the repeated code and then a more OO refactoring could commence, potentially moving the configuration and control into an object (I will avoid using the term "inversion of control" for fear of people confusing the basic design paradigm with the plethora of frameworks for implementing IOC).  I added a note in my last edit.

Comment: Good refactoring tips, you still need to pay attention to naming. Code in the answer is not c#.

Answer (score 15):

I would prefer something like this:

```
private void LoadGroup(string option) {
    Group group = GetGroup(option);
    string groupName = GetGroupName(option);
    Grid grid = GetGrid(option);

    BindGroup(group, groupName, grid);
}

Group GetGroup(string option) {
    // ideally this should be defined and initialized elsewhere
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Group>() {
        { "ALPHA", ManagerContext.Current.Group1 },
        { "BETA", ManagerContext.Current.Group2 },
        { "CHARLIE", ManagerContext.Current.Group3 },
        { "DELTA", ManagerContext.Current.Group4 }
    };   

    return dictionary[option.ToUpperInvariant()];
}

string GetGroupName(string option) {
    return option.ToLowerInvariant() + "Group";
}

Grid GetGrid(string option) {
    // ideally this should be defined and initialized elsewhere
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Grid>() {
        { "ALPHA", uxAlphaGrid },
        { "BETA", uxBetaGrid },
        { "CHARLIE", uxCharlieGrid },
        { "DELTA", uxDeltaGrid }
    };

    return dictionary[option.ToUpperInvariant()];
}

void BindGroup(Group group, string groupName, Grid grid) {
    VList<T> groupList = FetchInformation(group);
    if (Session[groupName] != null) {
        List<T> tempList = (List<T>)Session[groupName];
        groupList.AddRange(tempList);
    }
    grid.DataSource = groupList;
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

And now look how nicely we are insulated from changes. `GetGroup`, for example, can change how it finds groups and we don't have to worry about finding all the places where groups are looked up should those details need to change. Similarly for `GetGroupName` and `GetGrid`. What is more, we never repeat ourselves should any of the lookup logic need to be reused anywhere. We are very insulated from change and will never repeat ourselves when factored like this.

Comment: FYI: I don't think you need all those "new"s.

Answer (score 9):

Keep in mind, this is only a refactoring of what you've shown. Based on what you've shown, you may want to consider a deeper refactoring of your entire approach. This may not be feasible, however.

And so:

```
private void LoadGroup(string option)
{
        switch (option.ToUpper())
        {
                case "ALPHA":
                        BindData("alphaGroup", uxAlphaGrid, FetchInformation(ManagerContext.Current.Group1));
                        break;
                case "BRAVO":
                        BindData("bravoGroup", uxBravoGrid, FetchInformation(ManagerContext.Current.Group2));
                        break;
                case "CHARLIE":
                        BindData("charlieGroup", uxCharlieGrid, FetchInformation(ManagerContext.Current.Group3));
                        break;
                case "DELTA":
                        BindData("deltaTeam", uxDeltaGrid, FetchInformation(ManagerContext.Current.Group4));                        
                        break;
                default:                                
                        break;
        }
}

private void BindData(string sessionName, GridView grid, VList<T> data) // I'm assuming GridView here; dunno the type, but it looks like they're shared
{
    if (Session[sessionName] != null)
    {
            List<T> tempList = (List<T>)Session[sessionName];
            data.AddRange(tempList);
    }
    grid.DataSource = data;
    grid.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: I think you mean grid.Datasource, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar to this should work:

```
private void LoadGroup(string option)
{
        switch (option.ToUpper())
        {
                case "ALPHA":
                        BindGroup(ManagerContext.Current.Group1, "alphaGroup", uxAlphaGrid);
                        break;
                case "BRAVO":
                        BindGroup(ManagerContext.Current.Group2, "bravoGroup", uxBravoGrid);
                        break;
                case "CHARLIE":
                        BindGroup(ManagerContext.Current.Group3, "charlieGroup", uxCharlieGrid);
                        break;
                case "DELTA":
                        BindGroup(ManagerContext.Current.Group4, "deltaGroup", uxDeltaGrid);
                        break;
                default:                                
                        break;
        }
}

private void BindGroup(GroupType group, string groupName, GridView grid)
{
    VList<T> vList = FetchInformation(group);

    if (Session[groupName] != null)
    {
        List<T> tempList = (List<T>)Session[groupName];
        vList.AddRange(tempList);
    }
    grid.DataSource = vList;
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one just for fun (meaning it's unlikely to be a good idea and it's completely untested):

```
public class YourClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, Action> m_options;

    public YourClass()
    {
     m_options = new Dictionary<string, Action>
     {
      { "ALPHA",  () => LoadGroup(ManagerContext.Current.Group1, "alphaGroup", uxAlphaGrid) },
      { "BRAVO",  () => LoadGroup(ManagerContext.Current.Group2, "bravoGroup", uxBravoGrid) },
      { "CHARLIE",() => LoadGroup(ManagerContext.Current.Group3, "charlieGroup", uxCharlieGrid) },
      { "DELTA",  () => LoadGroup(ManagerContext.Current.Group4, "deltaGroup", uxDeltaGrid) },
     };
    }

    private void LoadGroup(string option)
    {
     Action optionAction;

     if(m_options.TryGetValue(option, out optionAction))
     {
            optionAction();
     }
    }

    private void LoadGroup(TGroup group, string groupName, TGrid grid)
    {
        VList<T> returnList = FetchInformation(group);

        if (Session[groupName] != null)
        {
                List<T> tempList = (List<T>)Session[groupName];
                returnList.AddRange(tempList);
        }
        grid.DataSource = returnList;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I'd only do something like this if I wanted to be able to dynamically alter (i.e. at runtime) the set of option matches, and I wanted the code executed (the load algorithm) to be completely open ended.

Comment: +1 The concept is right on the mark.  To extend this you only need to an additional entry to your Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
private void LoadGroup(string option)
{
    option = option.ToLower();
    sessionContent = Session[option + "Group"];

    switch(option)
    {
        case "alpha":
            var grp = ManagerContext.Current.Group1;
            var grid = uxAlphaGrid;
            break;
        case "bravo":
            var grp = ManagerContext.Current.Group2;
            var grid = uxBravoGrid;
            break;
        case "charlie":
            var grp = ManagerContext.Current.Group3;
            var grid = uxCharlieGrid;
            break;
        // Add more cases if necessary
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("option", "Non-allowed value");
    }

    VList<T> groupList = FetchInformation(grp);
    if (sessionContent != null)
    {
        List<T> tempList = (List<T>)sessionContent;
        groupList.AddRange(tempList);
    }

    grid.DataSource = List("alpha";
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

An alternative to throwing the exception is to re-type the option string into an Enum, with only the values you allow. That way you know that if you get a correct enum as input argument, your option will be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Make two functions, `GetGroup()` returning things like `ManagerContext.Current.Group4` and GetGroupName(), returning strings like `"deltaGroup"` . Then, all code goes away.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void LoadGroup(GridView gv, string groupName, ManagerContext m)
{
    VList<T> list = FetchInformation(m); //not sure if ManagerContext will get what you need
    if (Session[groupName] != null)
    {
       list.AddRange(List<T>Session[groupName]);
       gv.DataSource = list;
       gv.DataBind();
    }   

}
```